# accessing control from other html form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

using JavaScript i create an HTML form "NewForm", inside it , i will populate controls dynamically from JavaScript array locate in "MianForm" , how could i pass the array from main form to the new created form?

Comment: How is your Array expressed?  As a comma delimited string value of a hidden input element?  As an actual JavaScript Array in a pseudoproperty of the `<form>` element itself?

Comment: Thanks gilly3 , my array is JavaScript Normal Two Dimensional Array..

Comment: It would clarify what you are trying to do if you could post some sample code.  Specifically, where the array is defined, and how it is attached to the main form.  Typically, forms contain form elements (ie, input controls).  Forms *can* contain JavaScript objects (such as arrays), and that can be accomplished in a number of ways including being serialized and set as the value of a hidden input or being directly attached as a pseudoproperty of the form or one of its fields.  Can you clarify how your Array is located in the main form?  Or just post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using :

> jQuery('#header', **myWindow.document**).html();

i could be able to select any control in the new created HTML form. and so, i can pass any value to any html control in the form

```
myWindow.document
```

specifying which form you want to select control from.